# Change raster value for an area based on a class of another raster

Tags: raster, grass-gis, map-algebra

I would like to change all raster values in raster A that fall into the locations of category/class 1 of raster B.

Here, some more details. I did a calculation on a DEM resulting in different topography layers which I summed up to raster A. Now, I have a polygon map which I transferred into raster B. The class 1 of raster B should be an area that has only values of 1 in raster A. So I would like to use map algebra to change this (perhaps using a complex if() statement in GRASS GIS?)

I think I could have prevented all this earlier by simply applying a mask to the raster A before the calculations. However, the calculations took quite a while (2hours) so I would not like to repeat all the steps again...

any help is very much appreciated!
Jens

Answer (score 4):

sooorry guys! I already found the solution...

in GRASS GIS using the map calculator

if(rasterA == 1, rasterB  == 0, rasterB)

soo easy... :)

Comment: quite alright, just go ahead and select as the right answer, Maybe it would help others to know how/where you came across the answer.